# Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined when react build

Tags: javascript

when I using this command to build my project [cruise-web](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-web.git):

```
yarn build
```

shows this error:

```
[root@VM-0-16-centos cruise-web]# yarn build
yarn run v1.22.10
$ webpack --config config/dev.config.js
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined
    at getStatsOptions (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:238:45)
    at getStatsOptionsFromCompiler (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:243:63)
    at callback (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:247:19)
    at /home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:100:6
    at AsyncParallelHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncParallelHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Cache.shutdown (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:75:23)
    at Compiler.close (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:696:14)
    at /home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:99:14
    at finalCallback (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:227:39)
    at /home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:243:13
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:241:21)
    at /home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:682:16
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

this is my `dev.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
            presets: [
                ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
            ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
        "style-loader",
        "css-loader",
        {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                [
                    "postcss-preset-env",
                    {
                    // Options
                    },
                ],
                ],
            },
            },
        },
        ],
    },
    ],
  },
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
};
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Facing same issue with latest webpack-cli 4.2.0